# Read very large files from Google cloud storage usign Java

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloud, blob

I am trying to read a very large file (running to GB-s) from Google cloud storage bucket. I read it as Blob, and then open an InputStream out of the Blob.

```
"Blob blob = get_from_bucket("my-file");
   ReadChannel channel = blob.reader();
   InputStream str = Channels.newInputStream(channel); "
```

My question is, is the entire file moved to Blob object in one go or is it done in chunks? In the former case, it could lead to Out of Memory , right?

Is there a way to read the object from bucket just like we do with FileInpuStream so that I can read files irrespective of size of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#storage-stream-download-object-java), but, be careful: there isn't CRC enforced on this transfert mode. Some bit can be corrupted, and you can process data with errors.

If you process audio or video, it's not too important. If you handle big file of financial data with lot of numbers, I don't recommend this way.

Comment: I tried the snippet below ----> Path p = Path.of(URI.create("my file path in bucket"));
            InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(p);
            InputStreamReader fr = new InputStreamReader(in);   ------/ But, this throws an exception saying "provider for gs not installed". I think, this is due to an error in the way spring boot app is packaged

Comment: By the way, I am trying to read a file in GCP bucket from my spring boot api controller

Comment: Did you try with GCP and Spring Cloud integration? https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gcp Else, you will have to wrap and to code your own reader based on the streaming API: https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html#reader-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobSourceOption...-